# Taskbar Preview Pane + Mouseover Info Text: Is it possible?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, aero

I've noticed a couple similar questions (ie. [How to always show titles on Windows 7 Taskbar thumbail preview?](https://superuser.com/q/254390/101154)), but wanted to throw this out there to see if anyone knew of a way to achieve my specific goal.

Basically, I'd like to keep the Windows 7 Preview Panes if I can, but also get the old ability to mouseover a taskbar tab and see the full name of the application/page/etc that I currently. Is there a way to get this old mouseover textbox back without switching off of the Aero desktop?